# How to build to ISO C++03 in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++03, misra

Visual Studio 2017 only shows the ability to build:

- ISO C++14 Standard
- ISO C++17 Standard
- ISO C++ Latest Draft Standard

Is there a way to compile and build to ISO C++03 standard on VS2017?

We have to meet MISRA standards for c++ and it was written to c++03.
https://www.perforce.com/resources/qac/misra-c-cpp

So we have to build to that for software validation checks that we are using.

Comment: Visual Studio supports older toolkits. You may have to use one to get close to c++03 support. I am not sure how far you can go back. I have used the 2013 toolset with VS 2019. Related: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/use-native-multi-targeting?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/use-native-multi-targeting?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Visual Studio won't help you comply with such an old standard. In fact, at that time, Microsoft compiler were far from being compliant and up-to-date with the standard. In fact, I am pretty that the main reason they allows to select standard from C++14 is mainly because it is from that point that have decent compliance to a standard.

Comment: What is the intended target system and end application? Your requirements seem rather fishy, why exactly do you need MISRA compliance?

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that you need to install VS2012 to get the toolset. You could set `Platform  Toolset` to use C++03.
[image]

Comment: Is the entire VS2012 needed or only the compiler? The latter can be [done self-standing](http://blog.httrack.com/blog/2014/02/21/fancy-standalone-visual-c-plus-plus-compiler/).